# How to Create a Desktop shortcut to run multiple terminal commands Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, shortcut

I have a project on Raspberry Pi. I wish to create a short cut on the desktop (or automatically start the program if possible?) in which two terminal commands can be completed. I have seen some tutorials yet they have not worked for me as they only create text files.

i wish to run

`workon barcode`

followed by

```
python Scanner_Final
```

upon pressing the icon on desktop the pogram should run without the user having to type the terminal commands.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try something like `Exec=sh -c "workon barcode; python Scanner_Final"`

Answer (score 3):

You want a Shell script. Save a file called `scanner.sh` to your desktop with those two commands inside:

```
workon barcode
python Scanner_Final
```

Then make the file executable by right clicking it, "Permissions", "Make file executable" (or something similar, depending on your exact OS). Alternatively, open a terminal from your desktop and enter `chmod +x scanner.sh`.

Comment: thanks for this @samuelob - when i run this i get a syntax error with my shell script?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i added the lines to a bash script as i achived the desired outcome